# Rotate Image in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface

In my application I want to rotate image (I have set image on `QLabel`). I have set one `QPushButton`, on click that button I want to rotate my image in Four directions (Right->Bottom->Left->Top)

Any help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you have a pointer to your QLabel you could do something like

```
void MyWidget::rotateLabel()
{
    QPixmap pixmap(*my_label->pixmap());
    QMatrix rm;
    rm.rotate(90);
    pixmap = pixmap.transformed(rm);
    my_label->setPixmap(pixmap);
}
```

This will take you through Right, Bottom, Left, Top in four applications.

Comment: i get this for the first line where you fill the newly pixmap with my_label->pixmap():  'QPixmap::QPixmap(QPixmapData *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const QPixmap *' to 'QPixmapData *'
"

Comment: +1: Cool works! I'd only allow me to add one remark. QMatrix is meanwhile depricated. Replacing QMatrix by QTransform would comply with Qt4.8, Qt5 better.

Comment: Don't do this with images loaded from disk and save, you'll lose the metadata.

Answer (score 5):

**QMatrix** is deprecated so you can use **QTransform** instead

```
void MyWidget::rotateLabel()
{
    QPixmap pixmap(*my_label->pixmap());
    QTransform tr;
    tr.rotate(90);
    pixmap = pixmap.transformed(tr);
    my_label->setPixmap(pixmap);
}
```